# vim: How to cycle through a list of options using the same key?

Tags: vim

I want to cycle through a list of languages for spellchecking, e.g.

```
:setlocal spell spelllang=en_EN
:setlocal spell spelllang=en_US
:setlocal spell spelllang=de
:setlocal spell spelllang=fr
:setlocal nospell
```

with a single keypress.
One obvious way is to put each of these on a separate key, like F1 to F5. But this is hard on the precious few function keys I have. So I tried putting them on just one function key, which would *remap itself* to cycle through the list. But it turns out that the length of the mapping would increase with O(N^2). I believe there is a more elegant way of achieving this with vim functions, which I'm sure can keep state somewhere in a variable. Sadly, my vim programming fu is not developed enough to tackle this. (No, I don't want to use a menu in gvim).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
nnoremap <F2> :call CycleLang()<CR>

fun! CycleLang()
    let langs = ['', 'en_gb', 'en_us', 'de', 'fr']

    let i = index(langs, &spl)
    let j = (i+1)%len(langs)
    let &spl = langs[j]

    if empty(&spl)
        set nospell
    else
        set spell
    endif
endfun
```

Comment: Nice. But I think the OP wants to set the `spelllang` too

Comment: Sorry for the noise. I missed the line where you actually do that. Cool.

Comment: Sorry, I use `&spl` for short.

Comment: It makes me a [trusted user](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/trusted-user). :)